# Serving static index.html from the spa folder

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, single-page-application, static-files

I use .netcore server side and vuejs 2.

I have generated html files for some routes of my vuejs, that I placed directly in the `dist` folder:

[image]

I can access the html files with `http://my-domain/en/home/index.html`, but calling `http://my-domain/en/home` (without the `index.html`)  won't serve the html file. Instead, it will return the equivalent spa page.

What can I do to fix this? I want the server to return the html file if it exists in priority, otherwise return the normal spa website.

Here is part of my startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    // ...

    // In production, the vue files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => { configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist"; });

    // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // ...

    // WebRootPath == null workaround. - from https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6688
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(env.WebRootPath))
    {
        env.WebRootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp", "dist");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
        {
            const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24;
            ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
                "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
        }
    });
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

    // ...

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve", port: 8085);
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT**: On top of @Phil 's response, I needed to provide a FileProvider because `UseDefaultFiles` wasn't looking in the right folder:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(env.WebRootPath) // important or it doesn't know where to look for
});

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24;
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
            "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
    },
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(env.WebRootPath) // same as UseDefaultFiles
});
```

Comment: What's your server? Kestrel, IIS, ?

Comment: I use the default one: Kestrel

Comment: That seems odd about the FileProvider. From what I understood, the default files thing should just detect any requests for folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the server to use [Default Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-a-default-document)

> With `UseDefaultFiles`, requests to a folder search for:
>
> default.htm
>   default.html
>   index.htm
>   **index.html**

```cs
app.UseDefaultFiles(); // this must come first
app.UseStaticFiles(...
```

This basically sets up an interceptor for requests on a folder (like your `en/home`) and if it finds any of the above filenames, will rewrite the URL to `folder/path/{FoundFilename}`.

If you want to avoid searches for anything other than `index.html`, you can customise it

```cs
DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
options.DefaultFileNames.Add("index.html");
app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
```

---

Note the important information about ordering

> **Important**
>
> `UseDefaultFiles` must be called before `UseStaticFiles` to serve the default file. `UseDefaultFiles` is a URL rewriter that doesn't actually serve the file. Enable Static File Middleware via `UseStaticFiles` to serve the file.

Comment: I have been playing with this since this morning, it's definitely a missing piece of the puzzle. Unfortunately, it is not enough in my case. Although the file exists, it is not recognized by UseDefaultFiles as it doesn't rewrite the path as it should do. I'm pretty sure it is linked with the SPA that needs to use the dist folder content as wwwroot folder.